# Golang async behavior - why would I need waitgroups?

Tags: go

I am trying to get a grasp of async programming with golang and I have a question regarding channels and waitgroups.

From the docs I have read, that channel read/write operations block the execution. So if I needed return values from my go routines, I could just read the values at the end of the surrounding function by reading from the channels, so I have all return values from the go routines. In some examples tho, I see waitgroups beeing used to synchronize multiple go routines, I dont understand why I would have to use waitgroups if x := <- channel is blocking and I get the results that way.

Example Scenario: I want to fetch data from 3 different 3rd party APIs using GET

At the end of the function, I want to create some data structure out of all the results, so I would have to have all the go routines fetch results before creating that data structure from the results.

From my understanding if I put result1 := <- channel1, result2 := <- channel2, result3 := <- channel3 after calling the go routines, I have all the data asynchronous. Why should I do it with waitgroups instead?

Comment: Yes, you can do everything you need with channels, there was a time before WaitGroup when we did just that, and the first WaitGroup implementation was done with channels. Some patterns are just simpler with WaitGroup.

Comment: so waitgroups were introduced after channels?

Comment: Channels are a language primitive and a fundamental feature of Go, WaitGroup is implemented in a package.

Comment: Your question is analogous to asking why would you ever use a lock or semaphore or atomic exchange. As JimB commented the answer is that some programming patterns are simpler (or more efficient) using those mechanisms.

Comment: Example you have goroutines fetch data from some URLs and save to database, you just want to know when they finished then end the program. In this case, using WaitGroup makes more sense then waiting for a lot of goroutines without the need of transfering any data.